# how to add include paths to clang globally

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, include-path

I know this one way of adding include paths to clang:-
`clang++ -I <dir> a.cpp`

but with this, that path is only added for that particular file, and u have to write that every time linting, so how can I add some include paths globally to clint.

Comment: You could use a build system generator like CMake or write your own build system using Makefiles. That's what people typically do. If you feel particularly lazy/flamboyant you could write a shell script.

Comment: hmm actually I am kind of new to this, @AleksanderBobiński do you have any reference of how to do this with build system generator

Comment: Have a look at the CMake tutorial. It will help you in the long run. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are also some [environment variables](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#envvar-C_INCLUDE_PATH,OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH,CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH,OBJCPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) which Clang looks at for include paths. For c++, they would be `CPATH` (both C and C++) and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` (C++ only) (And `LIBRARY_PATH` for the linker). So you can add something like this to your shell startup file if you are using bash or similar:

```sh
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:+${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}:}<dir>"
```

And you could also just alias `clang++` with `clang++ -I<dir>`.

Comment: wouldn't I still need to add the config file every time linting? and ```clang++ -I<dir>``` does not work without specifying cpp.

Comment: @Vishnu you're right, their not global configs like I thought they were. You can still use the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` variable though, and the `alias clang++='clang++ -I<dir>'` means that `clang++ a.cpp` becomes `clang++ -I<dir> a.cpp` so you don't have to write the include